# How do you ignore but preserve ANSI escape codes with sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

If you were to print the string "`Hello, \e[38;5;200mworld\e[0m`", you might see "`Hello, world`" with the word "`world`" highlighted a strong magenta color (FF00DF) assuming your terminal supports it.

However, if you pipe the output of a program like `tree` to `column`, you'll see that the alignment is broken, since escape codes are incorrectly counted in line length calculations.

As a more direct example, I tried to split that string by characters in sed using the following:

`sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'`

...which yields...

`H e l l o ,   3 8 ; 5 ; 2 0 0 m w o r l d 0 m`

... when piped the string shown earlier.

How would you go about matching escape codes for the purposes of counting, replacing, preserving, etc. while editing a stream?

Comment: Why would you pass `tree` output to `column`. If you disable colorization (`tree -n | column`), do you get output that you want (except the color part)?

Comment: I don't; the color is still visible though, so I suspect one of my aliases is interfering. I pipe a lot of things to column when there's too much output to view without scrolling, which in a multiplexed terminal means not having to switch back and forth all the time. Of course I can scroll an unfocused pane and leave my original focused, but scrolling both still means moving the mouse. Aren't I lazy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is probably not exactly,
what you are looking for, but you can develop the idea further:

you can remove control characters
using `col`:

```
$ col -bx
```

or using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

You can use this regular expression
to extract sequences that should not be counted or processed other way.

Another interesting project, that can be useful for you
is [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php).

Comment: That one-liner sed is exactly what I was looking for! Merging the codes back in after editing the filtered stream looks like a very difficult task, but certainly a question for another day. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm looking at `filterdiff` in case anyone else is going down this path. I'm thinking that I can diff at each stage, first when I strip escape codes and second when I edit the stream, and then revert the changes from the first.

Comment: Do you think ansifilter can (help) match the phrase `apple` in `a\e[37;5;155mpple pi\e[me`? What if it ends up word-wrapped? Or, in `a<a href=''>pple pi</a>e` if you will, since it does other formats? I'm messing around with it now, but maybe you know the answer already. I assume there's no "right way" to do all of this, by the way, I'm only hoping for a best-guess attempt on a well-formed segment. I'm not even considering partial escape codes, orphaned open/close codes, etc.

Comment: Ansifilter is good at manipulating codes and the author's programs all play nicely with the different markup languages, and it can strip formatting, but it doesn't appear to have any way to restore the codes later. I think this problem is related to multiline regex if anyone's worked with that - you have to save and remove delimiters, modify the unbroken message, and restore the delimiters in relative position. In my experience that means finding an unused character like `\0` to substitute so I never collide with the source, but the tradeoff is that the replaced newline now matches patterns.